# ASIHTTPRequest + WCF POST XML

Tags: iphone, wcf, xcode, asihttprequest

I'm trying to make my app send data to a WCF RESTful webservice.

At this point I'm not getting any error message from ASIHTTPRequest but the web service not doing anything either.

Could you guys take a look at it and see if you can spot something?

Xcode

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mydomian.com/create"];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *myPostData = [[NSString        stringWithFormat:@"<Product><Description>desc1</Description><Id></Id><Name>some    body</Name></Product>"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSMutableData *myMutablePostData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:myPostData];

[request setPostBody:myMutablePostData];

[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml"];

[request setDelegate:self];

[request startSynchronous];
```

Webservice

...

public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }

```
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

...

[OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/create", Method = "POST", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
 void CreateProduct(Product product);

...

...CreateProduct...

myConnection.Open();

```
            string insertString = "insert into tbldata (desc,Name) values (@desc,@Name)";
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(insertString, myConnection);

            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@desc", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 12);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40);

            myCommand.Parameters["@desc"].Value = product.Description;
            myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = product.Name;


            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Have you tried to implement the delegate methods for this request? You should get error messages that will help you identify where the issue is.

Comment: setDidFinishSelector returns empty responseString. When I asked for responseStatusCode I got returned 200.

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks okay to me, but you could try testing it with another tool, like `curl` from the command line to be sure. Here's something to try:

```
curl -D headers.txt -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/xml' -d '<Product><Description>desc1</Description><Id></Id><Name>somebody</Name></Product>' http://www.mydomain.com/create
```

Check stdout for the response body and `headers.txt` for the response headers. You should get the same thing you're getting in your iOS app.

In terms of the server-side response, try responding with a different status code or body.